# Remove quotes from String in Python

Tags: python, string, speech-recognition, google-voice

I have a python Code that will recognize speech using the Google STT engine and give me back the results but I get the results in strings with "quotes". I don't want that quotes in my code as I will use it to run many commands and it doesn't work. I haven't tried anything so far as I didn't get anything to try!
This is the function in the  python code that will recognize speech:

```
def recog():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['./speech-recog.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    global out,err
    out, err = p.communicate()
    print out
```

This is speech-recog.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

hardware="plughw:1,0"
duration="3"
lang="en"
hw_bool=0
dur_bool=0
lang_bool=0
for var in "$@"
do
    if [ "$var" == "-D" ] ; then
        hw_bool=1
    elif [ "$var" == "-d" ] ; then
        dur_bool=1
    elif [ "$var" == "-l" ] ; then
        lang_bool=1
    elif [ $hw_bool == 1 ] ; then
        hw_bool=0
        hardware="$var"
    elif [ $dur_bool == 1 ] ; then
        dur_bool=0
        duration="$var"
    elif [ $lang_bool == 1 ] ; then
        lang_bool=0
        lang="$var"
    else
        echo "Invalid option, valid options are -D for hardware and -d for duration"
    fi
done

arecord -D $hardware -f S16_LE -t wav -d $duration -r 16000 | flac - -f --best --sample-rate 16000 -o /dev/shm/out.flac 1>/dev/shm/voice.log 2>/dev/shm/voice.log; curl -X POST --data-binary @/dev/shm/out.flac --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0' --header 'Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000;' "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=$lang&key=key&client=Mozilla/5.0" | sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' | awk -F":" '{print $4}' | awk -F"," '{print $1}' | tr -d '\n'

rm /dev/shm/out.flac
```

This was taken from Steven Hickson's Voicecommand Program made for Raspberry Pi

Comment: do you mean additional quotes to the quotes that represent a string in Python?   Include the command and output that you have, and what you specifically want.

Comment: There are many duplicates for "[python] remove string quotes"

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Just use string methods `.replace()` if they occur throughout, or `.strip()` if they only occur at the start and/or finish:

```
a = '"sajdkasjdsak" "asdasdasds"' 

a = a.replace('"', '')
'sajdkasjdsak asdasdasds'

# or, if they only occur at start and end...
a = a.strip('\"')
'sajdkasjdsak" "asdasdasds'

# or, if they only occur at start...
a = a.lstrip('\"')

# or, if they only occur at end...
a = a.rstrip('\"')
```

Comment: In my situation escaping the double quote didn't work so I used this instead...a = a.strip(chr(34))

Comment: why are you escaping the double quotes (")... using `a.strip('"')` is enough

Comment: @VivekPuurkayastha: yes you're correct, I escape the quote both for visual clarity and from general force of habit, so that if it's then pasted into some other quoted string it remains a quote character, and doesn't blow things up.

Answer (score 22):

You can use  eval() for this purpose

```
>>> url = "'http address'"
>>> eval(url)
'http address'
```

while eval() poses risk , i think in this context it is safe.

Comment: also worked for me. Thanks @koliyat9811
I was getting string like '\\'Acknowledged\\'' by using eval i got 'Acknowledged'

Comment: `literal_eval()` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)) is much safer than `eval()`

Comment: What is the risk of using eval, if I may ask?

Comment: @NwoyeCID Look up "python eval security"; but you can start here:
https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/#minimizing-the-security-issues-of-eval

Comment: Careful! Both `eval` and `literal_eval` will do much more than just strip the quotes – they will also *silently* evaluate all escape sequences in the string. A valid escape will silently be converted (`eval("'\xab'")` gives `'«'`), while any invalid escape or invalid syntax (!!!) will result in an error – try `eval("'\user'")` or `eval("'\images\raw'")`.

Answer (score 11):

There are several ways this can be accomplished.

- You can make use of the builtin string function `.replace()` to replace all occurrences of quotes in a given string:

  ```
  >>> s = '"abcd" efgh'
  >>> s.replace('"', '')
  'abcd efgh'
  >>>
  ```
- You can use the string function `.join()` and a generator expression to remove all quotes from a given string:

  ```
  >>> s = '"abcd" efgh'
  >>> ''.join(c for c in s if c not in '"')
  'abcd efgh'
  >>>
  ```
- You can use a regular expression to remove all quotes from given string. This has the added advantage of letting you have control over when and where a quote should be deleted:

  ```
  >>> s = '"abcd" efgh'
  >>> import re
  >>> re.sub('"', '', s)
  'abcd efgh'
  >>>
  ```

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is:

```py
s = '"sajdkasjdsaasdasdasds"' 
import json
s = json.loads(s)
```

Comment: how could '"sajdkasjdsaasdasdasds"' be json object?

Comment: a string (including with quotes) is a valid json string

Comment: Thank you! I tested double quotation again and get it!

Comment: Note that JSON will interpret several escape sequences automatically. This is likely not intended when just stripping quotes, and will produce unexpected output for any string using `\` such as Windows paths.

Answer (score 6):

This will remove the first and last quotes in your string

```py
import ast

example = '"asdfasdfasdf"'
result = ast.literal_eval(example)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
asdfasdfasdf
```

Answer (score 5):

You can replace "quote" characters with an empty string, like this:

```
>>> a = '"sajdkasjdsak" "asdasdasds"' 
>>> a
'"sajdkasjdsak" "asdasdasds"'
>>> a = a.replace('"', '')
>>> a
'sajdkasjdsak asdasdasds'
```

In your case, you can do the same for `out` variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
if string.startswith('"'):
    string = string[1:]

if string.endswith('"'):
    string = string[:-1]
```

Comment: The string methods `strip(), lstrip(), rstrip()` are for this.

Comment: `lstrip()` removes all characters of the same type from the left. `'""""hello'.lstrip('"') = 'hello'`. This may not be what OP wants.

Comment: Also, do you not think this approach is a bit naive? What if the quotes he wants to remove are in the middle of his string? Your solution would break.

Comment: @smci I wasn't talking to you. I was talking to Harald.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @Christian's comment:

Replace all single or double quotes in a string:

```
s = "'asdfa sdfa'"

import re
re.sub("[\"\']", "", s)
```