# How to uniformize the path input

Tags: python-3.x

I use this code to get the path of the excel file:

```
xlsx_path = input("excel path:")
print(repr(xlsx_path))
```

The user will give me `"C:\Users\Lenovo\test.xlsx"` or `C:\Users\Lenovo\test.xlsx`. But if user give me a `"C:\Users\Lenovo\test.xlsx"`**(Note the user will give me a redundant quotation mark)**, the `xlsx_path` will be `'"C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\test.xlsx"'` actually. Then I cannot recognize the path. How to get a uniform path regardless of user give me any path?

Comment: the_path = the_path.strip('\"') works for both cases giving the same result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove quotes from String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950791/remove-quotes-from-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If your users are typing in double-quotes around the filename, you can remove them by using the [.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method for strings. If there are no double-quotes around it, it will have no effect. Try this:

```
xlsx_path = input("excel path:")
xlsx_path = xlsx_path.strip('"')
print(repr(xlsx_path))
```