# Unwanted assignment of double quote in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, parameter-passing

So I have a list like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]
```

I have converted this list into a string:

```
"'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'"
```

The double inverted comma around the string only exists to wrap around the single inverted comma- I need the single inverted commas. The issue is when I input this string to a package that only takes this:

```
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
```

Of course, there is an error. Now, I have tried `.replace(' " ' , ' ')`, *string slicing*, and all others mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950791/remove-quotes-from-string-in-python/40950987). Nothing works as the double quotation is not part of the string but only exists to print it and is carried to the variable during the assignment.

EDIT:

Here is part of how I converted the list to string:

```
string=''
# ...
string = string + (" '%s '," %(items) )
```

EDIT to add more information because of the following comment:

I am playing with this [tool](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/blob/master/doc.md). In the following example all I am saying is that I am auto generating some variable to put in the third line but whatever I do, it invariably puts an additional comma around the string:

```
from dd import autoref as _bdd
bdd = _bdd.BDD()
bdd.declare('x', 'y', 'z') # ----------------------<this line>
u = bdd.add_expr('(x /\ y) \/ ~ z')
bdd.collect_garbage()  # optional
bdd.dump('awesome.pdf')
```

The error I get is:

```
AssertionError: undefined variable "a", known variables are:
 {"'x', 'y', 'z'": 0}
```

You will be able to generate this error if you simply replace the third line with this:

```
bdd.declare("'x', 'y', 'z'")
```

Comment: Please check the edited text above. Unfortunately, the reason for the error is what I already explained- an additional comma gets passed on to the variable as manually inputting **without the additional commas** doesn't give me any error.

Answer (score 4):

TL/DR: Need to provide single string names - solution further down.

---

The cool thing about a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is I can easily see what you are trying to do:

The method `bdd.add_expr(...)` wants *names* of variables as single strings - you try to provide a string with combined names which won't work, no matter how you add or interleave string delimiters.

The link to the original module code is also really helpfull. There is no `declare()` method in [bdd.py](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/blob/master/dd/bdd.py) - so I looked at its constructor [class BDD(_abc.BDD):](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/blob/master/dd/bdd.py#L122) and hunted the method down in its baseclass here: [_abc.py - delcare implementation](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/blob/master/dd/_abc.py#L49) which gives you:

> ````
> def declare(self, *variables):
>     """Add names in `variables` to `self.vars`.
>     ```python
>     bdd.declare('x', 'y', 'z')
>     ```
>     """
>     for var in variables:
>         self.add_var(var)
> ````

you can read more about this kind of parameter passing f.e. here:

- [Use of *args and **kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs) (and the dupe it links to)

---

Solution - provide the names instead:

```
from dd import autoref as _bdd

your_list = ['x', 'y', 'z']

bdd = _bdd.BDD()
bdd.declare(*your_list )   # provide list elements as single strings to function
u = bdd.add_expr('(x /\ y) \/ ~ z')
bdd.collect_garbage()  # optional
bdd.dump('awesome.pdf')
```

If you really want to go from a string, you need no string delimiters at all, simply provide the names:

```
from_string = "'x', 'y', 'z'" 

# this undoes all the stringifying of your list
as_list = from_string.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "',")).split()

bdd = _bdd.BDD()
bdd.declare(*as_list)   # provide list elements as single strings to function
u = bdd.add_expr('(x /\ y) \/ ~ z')
bdd.collect_garbage()  # optional
bdd.dump('awesome.pdf')
```