# Python Get Text in Quotes After Pattern

Tags: python, python-re

I want to get the text in quotations after the occurrence of the pattern "name".

A sample string is:
`info = "name: joe", "name: jerry", "name: kate"`

Here is what I'm doing:

```
import re

string = 'info = "name: joe", "name: jerry", "name: kate"'
array = re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', string)
for x in array:
       x = x.replace(" ","") #remove spaces because there might be space before colon occasionally 
       print(x.split("name:")[1])
```

The output prints:

```
joe
jerry
kate
```

I am just wondering if there is any easier way to do this and return the same output than what I did.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950791/remove-quotes-from-string-in-python

Comment: p = re.findall("(?<=name:[\s]{1})[a-zA-Z]+",string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed the `name:` pattern in the regex, account for the occasional space before the colon via `\s*` and also match one or more spaces after colon and the actual name (where you are splitting from):

```
re.findall(r'"name\s*:\s+(.*?)"', string)
# ['joe', 'jerry', 'kate']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
res=list(re.findall(r'\"name: ([^\"]+)"', string))

print(res)
```

2 important things - you extract only a group, hence the square brackets, and you define a name as set of one or more characters, that aren't double quotes `"`, since regex is on default greedy (i.e. matches the longest match only).

Outputs:

```py
['joe', 'jerry', 'kate']
```