# How to loop through directories and clean files?

Tags: python, valueerror

I am trying to loop through directories. My goal is to open the directory `ff` for modifications in the files.

When I try `open (ff, 'r')` it does not work.

Further, the files in the directories `d.txt` has numbers and symbols `x`, `1`, `"` in every line. I am seeking to remove these characters from each line.

```py
import os

filenames= os.listdir (".")
for filename in filenames:
    ff = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\V\Documents\f\e\e\data', filename, 'd.txt')

f = open(str(ff),'r')  #this line does not open the file
a = ['x','1','"']
lst = []
for line in f:
    for word in a:
        if word in line:
            line = line.replace(word,'')
            lst.append(line)
        f.close()
```

The Error that I am getting:

```
for line in f:
    ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: what is `folders`?

Comment: That exception is not produced in the code we see. There is no I/O operation here.

Comment: I belive you are doing the write operation outside the scope of file open, hence I/O error.

Comment: use not \ you need you use \\

Comment: Well you close the file with `f.close()` on the first iteration of `for word in a`, so if there's more than one word in the file it'll try to write to a closed file on the next iteration. You have to move that line out of the loops.

Comment: Why not use `with`?

Comment: @Yatin I tried `with` it is the same

Comment: Why do you think that the line you've commented doesn't open the file? The error message doesn't say anything about that line or about opening a file at all. The problem is trying to *close* the file multiple times, like I said before.

Comment: @Guy Incognito, yes you are right!

Comment: @Green, If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I think this part is wrong in your code:

```
    for filename in filenames:
        ff = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\V\Documents\f\e\e\data', filename, 'd.txt')
```

As this will assign the last filename to `ff`. So I have moved the following code under this for loop. Now it will run for all files.

I belive this code should work:

```py
import os 

filenames = os.listdir('.')

lst = []
a = ['x','1','"']

for filename in filenames:
    ff = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\V\Documents\f\e\e\data', filename, 'd.txt')
    
    with open(ff,'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            for word in a:
                if word in line:
                    line = line.replace(word,'')
                    lst.append(line)
                    
    with open(ff,'w') as file:
        for line in lst:
            file.write(line)
```

---

**Edit**: if the `open('ff','r')` line doesn't work then maybe the path you are giving is wrong. What are the contents of `filenames`? And why are you adding `d.txt` at the end?? Please edit your post and add these details.

Comment: Yes this code works,it loop through directories,  but somehow ' " '  quatation marks are not removed.

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40950987/11573842

Comment: The file needs closing. Without they are being ruined. lines from the last file are beeing saved in differen folder's file. but open(ff) works. So maybe this is a different question

Comment: @Green Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19508772/11573842

Answer (score 3):

Move `f.close()` to outside of loop. You're closing the file everytime loop runs.

```
import os

filenames= os.listdir (".")
for filename in filenames:
    ff = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\V\Documents\f\e\e\data', filename, 'd.txt')

f = open(str(ff),'r')  #this line does not open the file
a = ['x','1','"']
lst = []
for line in f:
    for word in a:
        if word in line:
            line = line.replace(word,'')
            lst.append(line)

f.close()
```