# How to get rid of double instances of quotations around a string?

Tags: python

I was wondering how you could convert the following list such that the strings contained in the list are properly formatted.

```
["'34872'", "'Johnathan'", "'Bonzo'", "'100'"]
```

Ideal output:

```
["34872", "Johnathan", "Bonzo", "100"]
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Remove quotes from String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950791/remove-quotes-from-string-in-python)

Comment: Start by filing a bug report with whoever produced that list :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` in a list comprehension

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> data = ["'34872'", "'Johnathan'", "'Bonzo'", "'100'"]
>>> [literal_eval(i) for i in data]
['34872', 'Johnathan', 'Bonzo', '100']
```

Otherwise you can use simple string replacement

```
>>> [i.replace("'", "") for i in data]
['34872', 'Johnathan', 'Bonzo', '100']
```