# dynamic path of the file using pandas - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am generating a CSV file using pandas, I need to create file based on the path stored in file.

Below is my code:

```py
HA_file_path = ''' select CONFIG_VALUE from CONFIGURATIONS where CONFIG_NAME = 'HA''''
```

I am getting syntax error here, not sure how to get value with single quote from table.

Also i need to attach file name with current date time.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but is the column name `'HA'` including the single quotes?

Comment: yes .'HA' is in single quote and i  a getting error over there

Comment: I am not sure on the standard with single and double quotes and escapation of characters. Try something like `"'HA'"`, I don't know... Maybe this will help? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901453/sql-standard-to-escape-column-names

Answer (score 1):

```py
import os
os.get_cwd()
```

returns current directory

```py
from datetime import datetime
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

returns current time & date

you can try concatenating this strings into your file name

Comment: thanks i got datetime , but how to get path from table with where condition

Answer (score 0):

Try stripping out the single and double quotes from the string variable that holds the file name.[strip quotes from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950791/remove-quotes-from-string-in-python)